# Multi-command with normal mode and execute mode

Tags: vimdiff

Using vimdiff, I can compare two files and generate it's corresponding HTML via the following command:

```
: TOhtml | wq | q | q
```

(the `wq` will save the `Diff.html` file, and the two `q`s will quit out of the two `vimdiff`ing files.)

Before I output to the `Diff.html` file, I'd like for all of the folds (places where code is identical between files) to be expanded.

I'm trying to run a command in Vim, like so:

```
:normal zo | TOhtml | wq | q | q
```

However, the result is not what I expected.  The above multi-command will only expand the folds (via `zo`); that is, it will ignore `TOhtml`, `wq`, `q`, and `q`.  I have to use the `normal` command because `zo` is a normal-mode command, as opposed to a execute-mode command.  It seems that when chaining commands after the normal command, the latter commands will not execute.

Edit: Although it appears you cannot have execute commands after a `normal` command, you can have a `normal` command after an execute command.  For example:

```
:q | normal zo
```

will in fact quit out of the first file's diff and then expand all folds in the remaining file's diff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [`:help :normal`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3Anormal):

```
This command cannot be followed by another command,
since any '|' is considered part of the command.
```

You can get around this by using [`:execute`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute):

```
:exe 'normal! zo' | TOhtml | wq | q | q
```

But perhaps it is better to make a function/command:

```
fun! DiffHTML()
    normal! zo
    TOhtml
    wq | q | q
endfun

command! DiffHTML call DiffHTML
```